# @Step is not reported

Tags: junit5, allure, playwright-java

I'm new to Allure,
I work with playwright + jave,
I'm trying to add steps to the report, but it seems that @Step Anotation is not reported in the allure test report,

I added to the pom:

```
<plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\${aspectj.version}\aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        </argLine>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/AllTests.tng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

@Test/@Attachment works well, only the @Step.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please add AllureTestNG listener to you testNG.xml file and corresponding Dependencies in your pom.xml. That should work

```
 <listeners>
        <listener class-name="io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg"/>
 </listeners>
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to specify systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled', 'true'
this is only for JUnit 5